# When does a number field have $p$-rank greater than $n$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, galois-cohomology

Consider $F/\mathbb{Q}$, a number field. Let $S$ be a finite set of primes of $F$ containing the Archimedean primes. Let $n$ be any natural number and $L_n$ be a finite extension of $F$ such that $\dim_{\mathbb{Z}/p}(Cl_{S}(L_n)/p)\geq n$. Can one give a bound on the discriminant of $L_n$ as a function of $n$?

By an iterative application of the Grunwald-Wang theorem (and Prop 10.10.3 of Neukirch-Schmidt-Wingberg) one can show that there exists a sequence $\{L_n\}$ such that each $L_n$ is in fact a $\mathbb{Z}/p$ extension. I am looking for a bound on the discriminant though.

Comment: I have no idea what the question is. Which parameters are fixed?

Comment: Given the number field, $F$ and the set $S$ we know that (from Prop 6.1 Lim-Murty, the Growth of Fine Selmer Groups) for each natural number, $n$ there exists a $\mathbb{Z}/p$ extension, $L_n/F$, such that $\dim \mathbb{Z}/p(Cl_S(L_n)/p)\geq n$. I want to find (an effective) lower bound on the (relative) discriminant $disc_{L/F}$ in terms of $n$.  I am even willing to consider the (probably easier) case $F=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: If the $p$-rank of $F$ is large enough, you can take for L a subfield of the Hilbert $p$-class field, and then the relative discriminant is $1$. In nontrivial cases I guess that the question is hopeless even for $n=1$.